# java.io.IOException: RandomAccessBuffer already closed, when reading a PDPage

Tags: java, runtime-error, pdfbox, random-access

I've created a program to convert a PDF to Excel. The conversion takes a long time (100 page=10 minutes). It runs fine for about 15-20 minutes, after that an error occurs when reading the PDPage.

Is it possible the Java GC "clean" the variable before the programs end?

the code:

```
private class Search_Text implements Runnable {

    private int x, y, width, height;
    private PDPage pdPage;
    private Object lock;
    private ArrayList<Object[]> result;
    private PDFTextStripperByArea strip;

    public Search_Text(int x, int y, int width, int height, PDPage pdPage, Object lock) throws IOException {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.pdPage = pdPage;
        this.lock = lock;
        this.result = new ArrayList<>();
        this.strip = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (height < 10) {
            int upper = y;
            int bottom = 1;
            ArrayList<Object[]> st = new ArrayList<>();
            String str = "";
            while (upper + bottom <= y + height) {
                strip.addRegion("cell", new Rectangle(x, upper, width, bottom));
                //System.out.println("prova.Pdf2Excell.log_extract()BEFORE LOCK" + init);
                synchronized (lock) {
                    try {
                        strip.extractRegions(pdPage);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Pdf2Excell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                str = strip.getTextForRegion("cell");
                if (!emptyString(str)) {

                    st.add(new Object[]{str, upper + bottom, upper});
                    upper += bottom;
                    bottom = 1;

                    while (upper + bottom < height + y && !emptyString(str)) {
                        strip.addRegion("cell", new Rectangle(x, upper, width, bottom));

                        synchronized (lock) {
                            try {
                                strip.extractRegions(pdPage);
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Pdf2Excell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                        str = strip.getTextForRegion("cell");
                        upper++;
                        //System.out.println("prova.Pdf2Excell.pdf2EX()DENTRO");
                    }
                } else {
                    bottom += 1;
                    //System.out.println("prova.Pdf2Excell.pdf2EX()UPPER;;"+upper+";;BOTTOM;;" + bottom);
                }
                if (upper == y) {
                    st.add(new Object[]{"", y + height, upper});
                }
                result = st;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                int half_rec = height / 2;
                Rectangle first_rec = new Rectangle(x, y, width, half_rec);
                Rectangle last_rec = new Rectangle(x, y + half_rec, width, height - half_rec);

                Search_Text first_search = new Search_Text(x, y, width, half_rec, pdPage, lock);
                Search_Text last_search = new Search_Text(x, y + half_rec, width, height - half_rec, pdPage, lock);

                Thread first = new Thread(first_search);
                Thread last = new Thread(last_search);

                strip.addRegion("cell", first_rec);
                synchronized (lock) {

                    strip.extractRegions(pdPage);

                }
                String temp = strip.getTextForRegion("cell");
                if (!emptyString(temp)) {
                    first.start();
                }

                strip.addRegion("cell", last_rec);
                synchronized (lock) {
                    strip.extractRegions(pdPage);
                }
                temp = strip.getTextForRegion("cell");
                if (!emptyString(temp)) {
                    last.start();
                }
                first.join();
                last.join();
                result = first_search.getResult();
                ArrayList<Object[]> temp_res = last_search.getResult();
                for (int i = 0; i < temp_res.size(); i++) {
                    result.add(temp_res.get(i));
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Pdf2Excell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            }

        }

    }
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-214418" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: RandomAccessBuffer already closed
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser$1.tryNext(PDFStreamParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser$1.hasNext(PDFStreamParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:255)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:458)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripperByArea.extractRegions(PDFTextStripperByArea.java:153)
    at prova.Pdf2Excell$Search_Text.run(Pdf2Excell.java:954)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: RandomAccessBuffer already closed
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.checkClosed(RandomAccessBuffer.java:325)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.seek(RandomAccessBuffer.java:105)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFileInputStream.read(RandomAccessFileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream.read(PushBackInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream.peek(PushBackInputStream.java:68)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.hasNextSpaceOrReturn(PDFStreamParser.java:560)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.parseNextToken(PDFStreamParser.java:408)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.parseNextToken(PDFStreamParser.java:374)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser.access$000(PDFStreamParser.java:49)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFStreamParser$1.tryNext(PDFStreamParser.java:193)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Please edit your question (by clicking `edit` underneath your question) and provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example) that reproduces the problem. Without seeing some code it is hard for us to tell what the problem really is.

Comment: Please mention what version you are using.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr pdfbox 1.8.10

Comment: Are you aware that PDFBox is not thread safe? https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/faq.html#threadsafe Each thread must have its own document. If several threads access the same PDPage object, or different PDPages of the same PDDocument, you'll asking for trouble.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I use exclusive reading with a lock ( see the code )

Comment: The code doesn't show how many lock objects there are, because the code is not complete - it doesn't show Search_Text being constructed. The input PDF would be nice too.

Comment: *I use exclusive reading with a lock* - but there is another thread doing something with the document when this thread is not in a `synchronized` block? If yes, that might cause havoc.

Comment: @mkl when the threads start, only the threads read the same PDPage and it's synchronized, but more threads read PDPage **from** the same PDDocument and this isn't synchronized, maybe is this the problem?

Comment: Ah, so synchronization only happens among threads reading the same page while threads reading different pages are not synchronized with each other? Hhmmm, I'm not sure that is a good idea. In particular there is a document-wide used scratch-file in PDFBox, I would not be surprised if multiple threads got into each other's way with that.

Comment: That been said, the architecture of your solution to me looks like you do `strip.extractRegions(pdPage)` again and again and again for the same page. This is very expensive, each time the whole page is parsed (which is a time-intensive task to begin with). Furthermore, adding a new region with the same name to the `PDFTextStripperByArea` is not what is is made for: Yes, in the internal name->rectangle map you replace the former region, but there also is a List of the names over which is iterated, and this list in your case contains the same name again and again. This list is used in loops...

Comment: ... This list is used in loops to iterate over to do region-specific tasks. In your case, therefore, these region-specific tasks are done very very many times too often. So it indeed is no wonder this takes ages to run. I'm sure this can be easily improved to speed up considerably. If you clearly defined your expected output, we might help there.

Comment: @mkl For the first comment: if this is the problem all i need is to use the same object as lock for each thread, right? For the second comment: I need to do this because I need to search a string and the y-coordinate where i find that, so I read the page until I find it... maybe it is better to create a new PDFTextStripperByArea each loop, if you say that....

Comment: *maybe it is better to create a new PDFTextStripperByArea each loop* - no, it is better to take `PDFTextStripper`, override `writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions)`, and collect the required information from that `List<TextPosition> textPositions`. `TextPosition` contains information on a small piece of text (usually a single letter, I think), including its position.

Comment: @mkl WOW, now it's like 4 times faster, thanks!

Comment: @GalloFlavio Have you run into any exceptions since the change I recommended? Otherwise I'd finish this by writing a matching answer.

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox has been developed for single-threaded use per document  while the OP *accesses the same document using multiple threads*. While this may still work (because it is a read-only use case), proper synchronization is necessary.

This synchronization most likely would have slowed down everything still more. Thus, the solution was to use a different architecture altogether, namely to

> take `PDFTextStripper`, override `writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions)`, and collect the required information from that `List<TextPosition> textPositions`. `TextPosition` contains information on a small piece of text (usually a single letter, I think), including its position.

The result turned out to be

> like 4 times faster.